# Syncing zoom and cursor across several date-based serial charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to implement the sync of cursor & zoom across several line charts following the example here.

http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/64dc766ec283e086c8ac8a5fba3bed83

I see the example does the below

```
var charts = [];
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", chartConfig));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", chartConfig2));
charts.push(AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3", chartConfig3));
```

and thereafter,

```
for (var x in charts) {
    charts[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
    charts[x].addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
}
```

The code for the listeners too iterate in a for loop.

**PROBLEM**

The below is the logic I use in the PHP file to retrieve the SQL result & then plot the amchart

```
for ( i = 1 to 10){
resultset[i] = exec_db_query(param1,param2...)
<script>
drawAmChart(resultset[i],val2,val3 etc)
</script>
}
```

The   `drawAmChart(resultset[i],val2,val3 etc)` makes a call to a javscript function `addListeners` that receives chart as the parameter.

As part of plotting the chart, I add listeners to it at the time of plot itself.
Hence my code for the below from the example

```
for (var x in charts) {
    charts[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
    charts[x].addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
}
```

is

```
function addListeners(chartObj) {
//    chartObj.addListener("init", handleInit);
    chartObj.addListener('init', function () {
        function legendHandler(evt) {
            if (evt.dataItem.id === 'all') {
                for (var i1 in evt.chart.graphs) {
                    if (evt.chart.graphs[i1].id !== 'all') {
                        evt.chart[evt.dataItem.hidden ? 'hideGraph' : 'showGraph'](evt.chart.graphs[i1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function syncZoom(evt) {
            if (chartObj.ignoreZoom) {
                chartObj.ignoreZoom = false;
            }
            if (evt.chart !== chartObj) {
                evt.chart.ignoreZoom = true;
                evt.chart.zoomToDates(evt.startDate, evt.endDate);
            }
        }

        function handleHideCursor(event) {
            if (event.chart.chartCursor.hideCursor) {
                event.chart.chartCursor.forceShow = false;
                event.chart.chartCursor.hideCursor(false);
            }
        }

        function addCursorListeners(event) {
            event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("changed", function () {
                function handleCursorChange(event) {
                    if (event.chart !== chartObj) {
                        if (event.position) {
                            chartObj.chartCursor.isZooming(event.target.zooming);
                            chartObj.chartCursor.selectionPosX = event.target.selectionPosX;
                            chartObj.chartCursor.forceShow = true;
                            chartObj.chartCursor.setPosition(event.position, false, event.target.index);
                        }
                    }
                }
                event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("changed", handleCursorChange);
                event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("onHideCursor", handleHideCursor);
            });
        }

        chartObj.legend.addListener('hideItem', legendHandler);
        chartObj.legend.addListener('showItem', legendHandler);
        chartObj.addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
        chartObj.addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
    });
}
```

This isn't working.

Could I request guidance on how to sync the charts in the way I'm implementing it please?

**UPDATED CODE - NOT WORKING YET**

Now, I make a call to `addChartScrollSyncListener` to synchronize all the charts on the page.

Firstly, the charts have disappeared. However, when I move my mouse over the chart div, I see the mouse cursor(chartcursor) that moves along & also the legend values!!

I get this error now in the debug console

```
TypeError: chartList[x].chartCursor.isZooming is not a function
chartList[x].chartCursor.isZooming(event.target.zooming);
```

Here is the `addChartSyncListener` function

```
function addChartSyncListener() {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        chartList[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
        chartList[x].addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
    }
}

function addCursorListeners(event) {
    event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("changed", handleCursorChange);
    event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("onHideCursor", handleHideCursor);
}

function syncZoom(event) {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (charts[x].ignoreZoom) {
            chartList[x].ignoreZoom = false;
        }
        if (event.chart != chartList[x]) {
            chartList[x].ignoreZoom = true;
            chartList[x].zoomToDates(event.startDate, event.endDate);
        }
    }
}

function handleCursorChange(event) {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (event.chart != chartList[x]) {
            if (event.position) {
                chartList[x].chartCursor.isZooming(event.target.zooming);
                chartList[x].chartCursor.selectionPosX = event.target.selectionPosX;
                chartList[x].chartCursor.forceShow = true;
                chartList[x].chartCursor.setPosition(event.position, false, event.target.index);
            }
        }
    }
}

function handleHideCursor() {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (charts[x].chartCursor.hideCursor) {
            chartList[x].chartCursor.forceShow = false;
            chartList[x].chartCursor.hideCursor(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first sight the code seems ok. Any results from debugging?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Hello Gerric - Thank you for jumping in. No error at all. Just that ater the graphs are plot, they behave independent of each other. I'm planning to get all the chart objects on the page & synchronize them with a for loop just like in example I've detailed.  How can I access all the chart objects on the page? Just like here - http://ahumbleopinion.com/highcharts-tips-accessing-chart-object-from-container-id/. I did try this.Amcharts.Charts & this.Amcharts.charts. Neither of these worked.

Comment: AmCharts is defined on the window scope, so querying the charts should work with `Amcharts.charts` (no this). My only thought concerning your code is, if the "inner" functions are correctly called from the listeners. Maybe try to use function expressions instead of declaring them.

Comment: Thank you Gerric. I managed to move the functions out of the nesting as at some point as I was fiddling with code, I started getting "too much recursion" error. I've updated the latest problems in the question under "
UPDATED CODE - NOT WORKING YET" section. Would you be able to help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing here is to be on the latest version of amcharts. The problem I had turned out to be a problem due to me being on version 3. Once I downloaded version 3.1.8, all works fine.

```
function addChartSyncListener() {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        chartList[x].addListener("zoomed", syncZoom);
        chartList[x].addListener("init", addCursorListeners);
    }
}

function addCursorListeners(event) {
    event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("changed", handleCursorChange);
    event.chart.chartCursor.addListener("onHideCursor", handleHideCursor);
}

function syncZoom(event) {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (charts[x].ignoreZoom) {
            chartList[x].ignoreZoom = false;
        }
        if (event.chart != chartList[x]) {
            chartList[x].ignoreZoom = true;
            chartList[x].zoomToDates(event.startDate, event.endDate);
        }
    }
}

function handleCursorChange(event) {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (event.chart != chartList[x]) {
            if (event.position) {
                chartList[x].chartCursor.isZooming(event.target.zooming);
                chartList[x].chartCursor.selectionPosX = event.target.selectionPosX;
                chartList[x].chartCursor.forceShow = true;
                chartList[x].chartCursor.setPosition(event.position, false, event.target.index);
            }
        }
    }
}

function handleHideCursor() {
    var chartList = AmCharts.charts;

    for (var x in chartList) {
        if (charts[x].chartCursor.hideCursor) {
            chartList[x].chartCursor.forceShow = false;
            chartList[x].chartCursor.hideCursor(false);
        }
    }
}
```